# Montando uma arena em canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Estou montando uma arena utilizando recursos de `HTML/JS` com o `canvas`.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
function montarArena() {
    var canvas;
    var heightCanvas = 498;
    var widthCanvas = 598;
    var qtdLinhas = $('#larguraCampo').val();
    var qtdColunas = $('#alturaCampo').val();
    var tamanhoLinha = widthCanvas / qtdLinhas;
    var tamanhoColuna = heightCanvas / qtdColunas;

    canvas = document.getElementById('imageView');
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillStyle = '#fff';
    context.clearRect(1, 1, widthCanvas, heightCanvas);

    console.log("tamColuna: " + tamanhoColuna + " tamLinha: " + tamanhoLinha + " QtdColunas: " + qtdColunas + " QtdLinhas: " + qtdLinhas);

    for (i = 0; i <= qtdLinhas; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j <= qtdColunas; j++) {
        context.strokeRect(j, i, tamanhoLinha * i, tamanhoColuna * j);
      }
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="larguraCampo" value="1" min="1" max="25" onchange="montarArena()" />
<input type="range" id="alturaCampo" value="1" min="1" max="25" onchange="montarArena()" />
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
```

A medida que a quantidade de linhas é acrescida, a arena vai ficando torta.... Do seguinte modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que ela fique ajustada, como se fosse uma tabela mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou percebendo aonde estou errando.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tinhas trocado a lógica dos argumentos, deve ser

```
context.strokeRect(tamanhoLinha * j, tamanhoColuna * i, tamanhoLinha, tamanhoColuna);
```

Da maneira que tinhas ele desenhava *N* quadrados todos a começar do canto superior esquerdo, no ponto de coordenadas `[i, j]`, o que quer dizer que o primeiro quadrado começava em `[0, 0]`, o segundo em `[1, 1]`, etc... e assim defasados/deslocados. O que estavas a variar era a área de cada quadrado.

Mudando como eu sugiro, crias quadrados todos com a mesma área e com o canto do quadrado reposicionado para `[tamanhoLinha * j, tamanhoColuna * i]`.

Comment: Muito bom @Sergio, era isso mesmo! O que a falta de um teste de mesa não faz rs. Uma unica correção, voce acabou invertendo a ordem do `tamanhoLinha * j` e `tamanhoColuna * i`, o correto seria `tamanhoLinha * i` e `tamanhoColuna * j`,